# How to add clickable website link into Snackbar?

Tags: android, android-snackbar

How to add clickable website link into Snackbar Android? Thanks.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace null with this code snippet.

```
  new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                       Intent browserIntent = new 
                       Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                       Uri.parse(getString(R.string.page_address)));
                       startActivity(browserIntent);
              }
      }
```

Answer (score 5):

**Try This.....Its Working for me**

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "www.google.com", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) 
snackbar.getView();

TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
       textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
       textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
       snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can linkify not only website URLs, but also email addresses, phone numbers, @ mentions, hashtags, and map addresses with this [LinkifyCustomized](https://gist.github.com/eclectice/9466727130350a3222c2670be279dda2) class:

```java
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(viewGroup, message, duration);
    final View snackBarView = snackbar != null ? snackbar.getView() : null;
    final TextView tv = snackbar != null? snackBarView.findViewById(R.id.snackbar_text) : null;
    LinkifyCustomized.addLinks(tv, LinkifyCustomized.WEB_URLS | LinkifyCustomized.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);
    snackbar.show();
```